# Strange character added when writing to file

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am writing the following line to the end of an html file as javascript. For some reason after the place variable is written to the file, a new line or some similar character is added. I wouldnt mind this because I won't be looking through the written script, but chrome is telling me its an illegal character.

Code to write to html:

```
map_html.write(
    "geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '" + place + "'}, function(results, status) {\n\
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker();\n\
      marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);\n\
      marker.setMap(map);\n\
      bounds.extend(marker.position);\n\
    });\n"
)
```

Output:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Brooklyn, NY
'}, function(results, status) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
          marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
          marker.setMap(map);
          bounds.extend(marker.position);
        });
```

Comment: Could it be a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ?

Comment: Any idea how to check?

Comment: Another issue: is there any possibility of `place` containing an unescaped single-quote character? Because that would cause problems.

Comment: @HughBothwell The question provides the rendered output. geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Brooklyn, NY
'} etc

Comment: @JoeFrambach: for _this_ input, that is true; I was talking more about the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
var geo_json = JSON.stringify({ 'address': place});
map_html.write(
    "geocoder.geocode(" + geo_json + ", function(results, status) {\n\
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker();\n\
      marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);\n\
      marker.setMap(map);\n\
      bounds.extend(marker.position);\n\
    });\n"
)
```

This will sidestep the issue and will allow you to see what the `stringify`ed json would look like. It's generally a bad idea to write your own json. Let javascript generate json, it's good at that.

If that still causes pain, then try `var geo_json = JSON.stringify({ 'address': place.trim()});` which will strip whitespace from the ends of the `place` string.

If that still causes pain, then try a regex to validate the `place` input. Something like `[A-Za-z_ ,]+`

---

**EDIT**

Oh, crap, I mixed up javascript and python here.

```
import json

geo_json = json.dumps({ 'address': place})
map_html.write(
    "geocoder.geocode(" + geo_json + ", function(results, status) {\n\
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker();\n\
      marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);\n\
      marker.setMap(map);\n\
      bounds.extend(marker.position);\n\
    });\n"
)
```

Comment: I'm confused. The write method is taking place in my python file, not my javascript. I know there is json in python but I cant find documentation for JSON.stringify(). Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I messed that up. I added an edit using python's `json.dumps`.

Comment: You got it! The power of json. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a multiline string?

```
map_html.write(
    "geocoder.geocode( { 'address': " + place + "}, function(results, status) {" + """
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
        marker.setMap(map);
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
    """
)
```